# URL rename error ["The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold"]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I can't rename a URL of a site (using the Site Settings>Title,Description and Icon)
I get the list view threshold error. But I changed the list view threshold on my server settings already. None of my lists exceed 4000. Huh?

I tried renaming from Designer & the SharePoint Website.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you also search in the ULS for that correlation id you've received and post all the lines related to that? One tool that can help you in that is [SPLIT](http://split.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SharePoint Designer doesn't work, maybe you shoult try doing this with PowerShell intead?

```
# Add PS Snapin if not loaded
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{    
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"    
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  -EA SilentlyContinue
}

#Iterate all webs and print List URL
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mydomain.com/"

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
        {
            if ($SPWeb.url.Contains("http://mydomain.com/sites/myweb"))
            {
                $SPWeb.Name = "myNewName"
                $SPWeb.Title = "My New Name"
                $SPWeb.Update()

                if ($SPWeb -ne $null)
                {
                    $SPWeb.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: This piece of script does not rename the list, it renames one site. But you don't have to iterate through all webs of an SPSite object and compare the URL to get the one SPWeb you need. You can just do the following: `$web = Get-SPWeb "http://mydomain.com/sites/myweb"`

Comment: @Norbert True, I thought it was renaming of the site that OP wanted by asking "I can't rename a URL of a site". And you're right, I don't have to iterate all sites for renaming just one. Just thought it would be easier if OP wanted to rename several sites

Comment: I am sorry, it seems that I wasn't really paying attention and the OP indeed was asking about how to rename a site, not a list :( My mistake.

Comment: @Norbert No worries, I'm not perfect either :)

Comment: Powershell Yeah! Your the man. Thanks Guys. Oddities of Sharepoint!(Powershell did take a bit... had to wait)

Answer (score 0):

For Reference This is what I used:

Start> 
[image: Click Powershell Modules on Server]

Run this script:

```
#Rename Site    
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://server/Prizm"        
$SPWeb.Name = "Prism"
$SPWeb.Update()
```